# Not able to get Country of a Tweet - Twython API

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am using the following code to collect Tweets pertaining to a certain topic but in all the tweets that I have extracted the 'places' attribute is None. Am I doing something wrong? Also, the code is meant to extract existing tweets and I do not need streaming api solution and not looking for this solution of streaming API : https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-get-a-stream-of-tweets-from-a-particular-country-using-Twitter-API

```
api =   Twython(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_key, access_secret)

tweets                          =   []
MAX_ATTEMPTS                    =   200
COUNT_OF_TWEETS_TO_BE_FETCHED   =   10000
in_max_id = sys.argv[1]
next_max_id = ''
for i in range(0,MAX_ATTEMPTS):

    if(COUNT_OF_TWEETS_TO_BE_FETCHED < len(tweets)):
        break # we got 500 tweets... !!

    #----------------------------------------------------------------#
    # STEP 1: Query Twitter
    # STEP 2: Save the returned tweets
    # STEP 3: Get the next max_id
    #----------------------------------------------------------------#

    # STEP 1: Query Twitter
    if(0 == i):
        # Query twitter for data. 
        results    = api.search(q="#something",count='100',lang='en',max_id=in_max_id,include_entities='true',geo= True)
    else:
        # After the first call we should have max_id from result of previous call. Pass it in query.
        results    = api.search(q="#something",include_entities='true',max_id=next_max_id,lang='en',geo= True)

    # STEP 2: Save the returned tweets
    for result in results['statuses']:

        temp = ""
        tweet_text = result['text']
        temp += tweet_text.encode('utf-8') + " "
        hashtags = result['entities']['hashtags']
        for i in hashtags:
            temp += i['text'].encode('utf-8') + " " 
        print result
        #temp += i["place"]["country"] + "\n"
        #output_file.write(temp)




    # STEP 3: Get the next max_id
    try:
        # Parse the data returned to get max_id to be passed in consequent call.
        next_results_url_params    = results['search_metadata']['next_results']
        next_max_id        = next_results_url_params.split('max_id=')[1].split('&')[0]
    except:
        # No more next pages
        break
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so what type of error?

Comment: No errors. Just that the "places" attribute is empty !

Comment: Edit your code according to my answer, then it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If `place` field is a MUST for all the tweet that you app will process, then you can limit your search over a place to make sure all the result will definitely have it.

You can doing so by setting `geocode` (latitude,longitude,radius[km/mi]) parameter, to limit your search within an area.

An example such request via Twython is:

```
geocode = '25.032341,55.385557,100mi'
api.search(q="#something",count='100',lang='en',include_entities='true',geocode=geocode)
```

Comment: This answer is not technically correct.  This filter just ensures that results are more likely to have a place assigned.

Comment: This answer is also not correct because `search/tweet` actually does return `place` tags. However, the `place` tag is almost always empty. Only about 1% of all tweets have data in `place` tag.

Comment: @Jonas Ive rephrased my answer. and its not "technically" wrong, it is completely depends on app's need and how you want to use the result.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, No, you are doing nothing wrong. The reason why all `place` tags are empty is because statistically they are very unlikely to contain data. Only about 1% of all tweets have data in their `place` tag. This is because users rarely tweet their location. Location is off by default.

Download 100 or more tweets and you probably will find `place` tag data.

Answer (score 0):

Not all tweets have all fields like tweet_text, place, country, language etc.,

So, to avoid `KeyError` use the following approach. Modify your code so that when the `key` that you're looking for is not found, a default value is returned.

```
result.get('place', {}).get('country', {}) if result.get('place') != None else None
```

Here, the above line means "search for the key `country` after fetching the key `place` if it exists, otherwise return `None` "

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I have written that there is no error. Its just that the place attribute is NONE. So thanks but it will not be helpful in this case.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. You need to get more tweets. I inspected ~50k tweets, but I were able to find only a hundred "place" field, the rest were "null". Inspect the fetched JSON before processing.

Answer (score 0):

kmario is right.  Most tweets don't have this information, but a small percent do. Doing a location search will increase this chance  e.g. https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=place%3Acba60fe77bc80469&count=1

```
  "place": {
    "id": "cba60fe77bc80469",
    "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/cba60fe77bc80469.json",
    "place_type": "city",
    "name": "Tallinn",
    "full_name": "Tallinn, Harjumaa",
    "country_code": "EE",
    "country": "Eesti",
    "contained_within": [],
    "bounding_box": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            24.5501404,
            59.3518286
          ],
          [
            24.9262886,
            59.3518286
          ],
          [
            24.9262886,
            59.4981855
          ],
          [
            24.5501404,
            59.4981855
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "attributes": {}
  },
```